# docker-compose exec workspace bash - DOES NOT OPEN ANYTHING

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mintty

I'm doing a class project, I have to follow some steps and there's one that is not working. Here's the problem.

I have to use:

```
docker-compose exec workspace bash
```

To open a directory and be able to write there:

```
 /var/www$ composer install
```

In Docker everything seems to be okay installed and configured.

The problem is that docker-compose exec workspace bash is not working. I wrote that in the console and nothing happens or opens VISUALLY. Image below:

[image: Nothing happens]

But internally, there is something that executes, because when I try to close the window of the console this appears "Processes are running in session":

[image: Error]

What's wrong? ¿How can I open docker-componse workspace? Thank you in advance.

Comment: your himework arready wa posted multple times and i thing nobody has an answer for this

Comment: Someone answered and it worked!

Comment: Please share any relevant code by editing your Question - [instead of a screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Fewer people are likely to reproduce your issue without having your code in a copyable form.

Answer (score 1):

One way to access a shell inside your workspace container is to directly exec ur composer inside the container with the command `docker exec`
Try this:

```
docker ps
```

Now find the container id of your workspace container

```
docker exec -it [container_ID] bash
~$ composer install
```

Comment: That worked! Amazing :) Thank youuuu so much